# Скрипт запуска forever после пуша в конкретную ветку не отрабатывает полностью

Tags: linux, git, bash, gitlab, githooks

Есть gitlab, нужно выполнить такой bash-скрипт после пуша к примеру в ветку master

```
#!/bin/bash 
git archive --remote=/repositories/myproject.git master | tar -x -C /www/myproject/

forever stop "myproject"

cd /www/myproject

export NODE_PATH=.
export NODE_ENV=qa
export NODE_INIT_TARGET=build

node --use_strict bin/init

forever start -a --uid "myproject" --minUptime 5000 --spinSleepTime 5000 bin/start --use_strict

exit 0
```

Здесь `node --use_strict bin/init` запускает сборку проекта (фронт-енд) перед стартом.

Сейчас это все дергается post-recive хуком - php-скриптом, при этом срабатывает только `git archive ...`, все что далее не выполняется. Вопрос почему? Как сделать чтоб работало?

Тут же, скажу, что может веб-хук это фигня? Может куда-то можно засунуть этот bash-скрипт в гитлаб, и выполнить его без всяких http-запросов на прямую на сервере? p.s. последний вариант был бы идеален) Подскажите как решить проблему? Может как-то можно средствами gitlab?

Comment: `post-receive` hook? Кстати, а как вы определили, что именно после той строки всё остановилось? И вот интересное чтиво: https://help.github.com/enterprise/2.8/admin/guides/developer-workflow/creating-a-pre-receive-hook-script/

Comment: @0andriy так, что логи приложения пусты а файлы обновились